# "Unexpected null value" error when trying to write data to cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am working on a sign up page for a web app. The code below shows how I am trying to authenticate users as well as add their data to cloud firestore. However I am getting an error saying that something is null even though I make sure to fill out the sign up info correctly.

I am assuming that the error comes from the try/catch block towards the bottom. I have followed the docs on flutterfire website to add user data to the cloud firestore database
(https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage).

Also, what would be the best way to implement the addUser() function to avoid errors?

here is my code:

```
class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  User? firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference firestoreData =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    Future<void> addUser() {
      return firestoreData
          .add({
            'email': emailController.text,
            'name': nameController.text,
            'login_UID': firebaseUser!.uid,
            'isCounselor': false,
          })
          .then((value) => print("User Added"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(300),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Prénom'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: passwordController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Mot de Passe'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text('Sign up'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: emailController.text,
                            password: passwordController.text);
                    addUser();
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                      print('The password provided is too weak.');
                    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                      print('The account already exists for that email.');
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
                },
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error?  Have you used console.log or other to *see* the values you "know" aren't null? Forty years of debug experience: you don't "know" anything you haven't just seen!  Just because you "know" it "should" work doesn't mean it is.

Comment: I have not console logged anything. I am not really sure what the means. The error shows up on the android studio "run" window. The error comes from the catch(e) line at the end of the code snippet. I posted the question yesterday, and for some reason it is working this morning. Thank you for your help though! Like you said, I should not assume that I "know" until I have seen.